# I want to change progressBarProgress value

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, setinterval

```
const Loader = props => {
 const {
loading,
progressBarProgress=0.00250,
PleaseWait,
...attributes
 } = props;

 changeProgress = () =>
 {
this.value= setInterval( () => {
  if(progressBarProgress <= 1)
  {
    console.info(progressBarProgress+.10)
  }
    }, 100 );
  }
```

I am try to create loading with progress bar and i want to change progressBar 
 value with interval

Comment: It is a `const`, I doubt you can modify it.

Comment: use `let` instead of `const`

Comment: if you want to modify use let instead of const

Comment: @ManojBhardwaj: You would have had, from what was in your question originally. And PLEASE DON'T SHOUT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. This (from your edited question):

```
const Loader = props => {
    const {
        loading,
        progressBarProgress=0.00250,
        PleaseWait,
        ...attributes
    } = props;
    // ...
```

...defines *constants*. Your constants are just that: constants. As in, they cannot be changed.

If you want to be able to change them, use `let` instead of `const` for the ones you want to be able to change.

---

**However**: I suspect you'll need to revisit your overall design; if this `Loader` is going to have state that changes over time, you don't want to define it as a stateless functional component (SFC) like that. You can use an SFC that gets re-rendered by its parent with an updated `progressBarProgress` property, or you can use a non-SFC (`class Loader extends React.Component`...) that accepts an *initial* progress property but then updates its own state (via `setState`). But what you've shown of what you've got so far is going down a hybrid SFC-but-with-state which won't work.

Comment: I am also using progress bar with loader so i have to set timer for that

Comment: @ManojBhardwaj: Right, but again, you can't use an SFC that has changing state. You can use an SFC where it gets re-rendered by its parent, or you can use a non-SFC that updates its own state. This hybrid won't work.

Comment: Can i used constructor here

Comment: @ManojBhardwaj: Yes. Again, if it's going to update itself rather than be updated by its parent, you'll want to make it a component class. See the documentation for how to do that. Or, again, have the parent update it with updated props.

Comment: <ProgressBarAndroid  color="#006fbc" styleAttr='Horizontal' progress = {progressBarProgress } 
                  indeterminate={false} style={{width:'90%'}}/>  for now i am using let but progressBarProgress  not updated

Comment: @ManojBhardwaj: Right. See above. I've explained at least twice that you can't do that, and what to do instead.

Answer (score -1):

Your can update const object property as follow..

```
const pInfo = {
    loading:false,
    progressBarProgress:1.05
};
setTimeout(()=>{++pInfo.progressBarProgress;},1000);
```

Comment: It's not an object.

Comment: I don't think that the question is asking how to update a property on a constant object reference; the question is how to update a constant.

Comment: In above question it's very clear "How can I Update value of a const in javascript", And @Manoj Bhardwaj is asking for "want to update progressBarProgress value". So i answered.

Comment: Thank you Omprakash Sharma for your effort